# Recursive function to count number of nodes with two children in BST

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree

I need to implement this recursive function that will take a root of a BST and recursively count the number of nodes in it with two childrens, but i am not sure if my logic is correct?

My logic is:

1. If leaf or empty we return 0
2. You check if a node with two children we add one and call again on its left and right children
3. Else if a node doesnt have two children you  call on its left and right subtrees without adding

Here is my function implementation
ps: assume everything in the **BinarySearchTree** class is implemented:

```
int count(BinarySearchTree *root  )
{
    if(root== nullptr)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if(root->right != nullptr and root->left!= nullptr)
    {
        return  1+count(root->right)+count(root->left);
    }

    count(root->right);
    count(root->left);

}
```

Comment: You don't really have a question here, do you want to know how to fix your code?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Sorry my question is if my logic was correct

Comment: In your exposed code, there is a path without return. (I believe your compiler will tell you same.)

Comment: Can you add some sample input and expected output? I am kinda confused with inclusion or exclusion of subnodes count.

Comment: @Matcha_boy98 If the question is to count all nodes that have 2 children, you can also use Morris traversal to make it O(1) space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to sum up the counts even if your node doesn't have two children. Two count calls that you have after if are basically not used.
You can fix it like this:

```cpp
int count(BinarySearchTree *root  )
{
    if (root== nullptr)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int countForThisNode = root->right != nullptr and root->left!= nullptr;
    return countForThisNode + count(root->right) + count(root->left);
}
```

In this case `countForThisNode` is 1 for the node that you want to count and 0 otherwise. All other nodes are added to the result no matter what.

I hope this is information you were asking for!

Comment: elegant and beautiful, was my implementation though correct?

Comment: Do you intend to count a node only if it has two children? This is what I read from `int countForThisNode = root->right != nullptr and root->left!= nullptr;`.

Comment: @Scheff yes only nodes with 2 children should be counted

Comment: @Matcha_boy98 I somehow missed the _the number of nodes in it with two childrens_. ;-)

Comment: @Matcha_boy98 your implementation doesn't count nodes that have two children, but on their way from root have nodes that have only one child (which is a possible situation in BSTs). Also, your program will even crash because you don't return from your second half. You can at least need to do `return count(root->right) + count(root->left);` there.

Comment: @ValeriySavchenko i thought if(root->right != nullptr and root->left!= nullptr) will be able to count number of nodes with two children since only then i will increment?

Comment: @Matcha_boy98 you still need to count whatever is happening below even if the node doesn't have two children. It can be more nodes satisfying this condition. As you do not return from function if condition is not satisfied you will not include those nodes.

Comment: @ValeriySavchenko " As you do not return from function if condition is not satisfied you will not include those nodes " what about the count after the if statements?  count(root->right);
    count(root->left);

Comment: @Matcha_boy98 you don't use return values of these two calls in any way

Answer (score 3):

Your function has undefined behaviour because the control can be transfered to the closing brace without returning anything.

```
    count(root->right);
    count(root->left);

}
```

For starters as the list is not changed the parameter should have the qualifier `const`.

The function can be defined much simpler the following way

```
unsigned int count( const BinarySearchTree *root  )
{
    return root == nullptr ? 0
                           : ( root->left && root->right ) + count( root->left ) 
                                                           + count( root->right );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to implement this function:

- start from a *standard* enumeration of the nodes (can be prefix, infix, suffix, doesn't matter);
- modify it so that at every node you increment the counter if there are two children.

Note that you need to look at the whole tree, as parts of it may be reached via single-childrened nodes.

---

```
visit(root):
  if root.left != null:
      visit(root.left)
  if root.right != null:
      visit(root.right)
```

becomes

```
visit(root):
  count= root.left != null and root.right != null
  if root.left != null:
      count+= visit(root.left)
  if root.right != null:
      count+= visit(root.right)
  return count
```

---